# Unix/C++ code that reads lines of text, breaks them into words, and runs the result

Tags: c++, c, shell, unix

The program should execute some loop:

1. Issue a prompt and read one line of text.
2. Break that line into words.
3. If the command is a built-in, take care of it yourself, and return to the read step. Otherwise,
4. Execute a fork to create a new process. Report the cause of any failure (and, -of course, don't exec if the fork failed).
5. The child process treats the first word in the list as the name of a command and runs it using an exec call. Send the whole list as the parameters to the program. Report the cause of any failure.
6. The parent process waits for the child process to exit, then reports its status.
7. Back to the read for the next command.

I write the head, body, and implementation below

This is the line parsing class:

```
 #include <string>

using namespace std;

/*
 * This class takes a C++ string and provides an array of plain C strings
 * (array of pointers to char) representing the words in the line.
 */

class LineBreaker {
public:
        // Construct the object, providing the line of text to be
        // broken up.
        LineBreaker(const string &s);

        // Clean up.
        ~LineBreaker() {
                delete [] m_data;
                delete [] m_parmlist;
        }

        // Return an pointer to the first slot of an array of pointers
        // containing the words in the string sent to the constructor.
        // The list is terminated with a NULL pointer.
        char **parmlist() { return m_parmlist; }
private:
        char *m_data;           // Dyn array of characters from the string.
        char **m_parmlist;      // Array of words
};
```

This is runner program which is body:

```
    /*
     * Simple program to demonstrate the fork/exec/run sequence for creating
     * processes in Unix.
     */

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>

    #include "linebreaker.h"

main()
{
        /* Ask for a program to run.  This is just the file name of an
           executable. */
        cout << "Your command? ";
        string cmd;
        getline(cin, cmd);

        LineBreaker breaker(cmd);

        /* Create a child process and try to run the program in it. */
        if(fork() == 0) {
                execv(breaker.parmlist()[0], breaker.parmlist());
                cout << "Sorry, the exec failed." << endl;
                exit(1);
        }

        /* See what was the cause of the child processes' demise. */
        int status;
        wait(&status); /*we only need to change this part, and use something like this if(string(breaker.parlist()[0]) == "exit") */
        if(WIFEXITED(status)) cout << "Exited." << endl;
        else if(WIFSIGNALED(status)) cout << "Killed." << endl;
        else cout << "Mysteriously vanished." << endl;
}

/*
 * Note: This program really should check the return values for fork() and for
 * exec() to make sure they succeeded, and print an error message if not.
 * Failure is indicated by a negative return value.  It would also help to use
 * errno and strerror() to print a descriptive error message in place of the
 * existing exec() failure message, or for the new messages.
 *
 * It also uses uses gets() and fixed-size buffers, which creates a risk of
 * buffer overflow.
 */
```

This is the implementation :

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

#include "linebreaker.h"

LineBreaker::LineBreaker(const string &s)
{
        // Copy the string as a character array.
        m_data = new char[s.length()+1];
        strcpy(m_data, s.c_str());

        // Find all the words.
        char last = ' ';
        list<char *> parts;
        for(char *scan = m_data; *scan; ++scan) {
                char curr = *scan;

                if(isspace(last) && !isspace(curr))
                        parts.push_back(scan);
                else if(!isspace(last) && isspace(curr))
                        *scan = '\0';

                last = curr;
        }

        // Allocate the array of pointers for exec, and copy the
        // pointer into it.  Then add the NULL terminator.
        m_parmlist = new char * [parts.size()+1];
        copy(parts.begin(), parts.end(), m_parmlist);
        m_parmlist[parts.size()] = NULL;
}
```

I want to wrap most of the code of the existing runner program in a while loop, so that it will repeatedly read and execute a command, rather than reading one and exiting.

In the runner program, entering a blank line creates an error (the exec will fail). Change the program so entering a blank line (no words, therefore no command name), doesn't run any command, but the program just returns to the promp then reads another command.

This version searches for command files in the usual places, so don't have to find the full path of the file you want to execute. The runner program uses execv; simply replace with execvp.

Check the return code from each of the fork, exec, or wait calls to check for failure. I want to use errno and strerror to print a message giving the cause of the failure. implement two commands that cannot be run using fork/exec. These are the exit command, and the cd command. These are the build-in commands that the shell must execute itself. For status reporting, if the program exits with a code other than 0 (an error exit), or if it crashes, report that. For normal exit, say nothing. Report the exit code, or the reason for the crash. More on this below.

Comment: What is the question?????????????????

Comment: the problem is wrap runner program into a while loop so it can solve the listed 8 problems

Comment: So you basically want to put everything within `main()` in a loop. Seems easy enough for someone who wrote all that code, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `apt-get source dash` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, because this is homework, but here’s a hint: `while (std::getline( std::cin, cmd ))`

This works because `getline()` returns a reference to the input stream, and when you cast that to a `bool` value, it will return `true` while the stream hasn’t yet encountered end-of-file or an error.